# parent term and child term taxonomy showed in multiple select checkbox dropdown Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have some custom taxonomies built in theme, and on the taxonomy dropdown, taxonomies are showed in hierarchy. It just show a dropdown list of all taxonomies, but how to display them into multiple select checkbox?

This is what I've got:

```php
<label><strong>Building / Place Amenities</strong></label>
<?php
/** The taxonomy we want to parse */
$taxonomy = "place_amenity_taxonomy";
/** Get all taxonomy terms */
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array(
        "orderby" => "count",
        "hide_empty" => false
    )
);
/** Get terms that have children */
$hierarchy = _get_term_hierarchy($taxonomy);
?>
<select name="terms" id="terms">
    <?php
    /** Loop through every term */
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        /** Skip term if it has children */
        if ($term->parent) {
            continue;
        }
        echo '<input type="checkbox" value ="' . $term->name . '">' . $term->name . '</input>';


    }
    ?>
</select>
```

wanna display the taxonomy list like this : [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXZxi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean by "but how to display them into multiple select checkbox?", but you can add multiple to the select and get an array of results back for it `<select name="terms" id="terms" multiple>`

Comment: wanna show the output just like above, it display dropdown with containing checkbox that can be select (multiple).

Comment: @Sam that is not the default behaviour of the `select`. if you want a check box you will need to use a 3rd party or roll a custom one.

Refer to this as to how it works by default
https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple